# Database retrieval error "Process exited before completing request"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I've got problem with getting data from database via AWS lambda. I've got code in Node.js:

```
   'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

let doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
let dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

       if (event.tableName) {
          event.id.TableName = event.tableName;
      }

    dynamo.getItem(event.id, callback);
    callback(null, event.id);  // Echo back the first key value
    // callback('Something went wrong');
};
```

And testing it with such a JSON code:

```
 {
  "tableName": "Events",
  "payload": "dbf943c3-aaac-473d-9c6a-7651280e0f90"
}
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

PS. My Database is called Events and id of the record which I want to get is: dbf943c3-aaac-473d-9c6a-7651280e0f90

Comment: Why are you passing the Lambda callback to the getItem() function call? I'm pretty sure that's not going to do what you want. You need to write your own callback function to pass to that (or switch to using promises).

Comment: Could you write the code of this function for me, please?

Comment: If you don't know how to write basic NodeJS code then trying to learn that and AWS Lambda and DynamoDB all at the same time is going to be a painful experience.